# Custom routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes

I have a users controller.

For a specific user I want to have something like this

```
 example.com/a_constant_string ==> example.com/users/2
```

I just need for a specific user, not for all users. You can say

```
link_to 'Go to a specific user', @user
link_to 'Go to a specific user', user_path(@user)
link_to 'Go to a specific user', a_constant_string_path
```

Should be same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a redirect route in config/routes.rb:

```
match '/a_constant_string', :to => redirect("/users/2")
```

Which would redirect to the correct path, and gives you the URL and PATH helpers: `a_constant_string_path` and `a_constant_string_url`.

Answer (score 6):

This would work too:

```
match '/a_constant_string', {controller: 'users', id: 2}
```

with the added benefit (IMO) of not sending a browser redirect.